# How to update array after post method

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, observable, crud

I'm adding a new Task to my RESTful web Service and in subcribe method I update my tasks array in angular. New Task is displayed in browser right away but if I want to delete it, this task always has id equal 0. If i refresh site (call ngInit) delete is working correct. I think I have to do something diffrent in my subscribe method to get new tasks with its new id from backend service.

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {TaskDataService} from "./tasks/task-data.service";
import {Task} from "./tasks/task";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css'],
  providers: [TaskDataService]
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

  tasks: Task[] = [];

  constructor(private taskDataService: TaskDataService) {
  }
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.taskDataService
      .getAllTasks()
      .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks)
  }
  onAddTask(task: Task) {
    this.taskDataService
      .addTask(task)
      .subscribe(
        (data: Task) => {this.tasks.push(data)}
      );
  }
  onToggleTaskComplete(task) {
    this.taskDataService.toggleTaskComplete(task).subscribe((updatedTask) => {
      task = updatedTask;
    });
  }
  onRemoveTask(task) {
    this.taskDataService.deleteTask(task).subscribe();
    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(t => t.id !== task.id);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Task} from "./task";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/observable/of";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {environment} from "../../../environments/environment";

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class TaskDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error, 'Operation: ${operation}');

      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
  addTask(task: Task): Observable<Task> {
    return this.http.post<Task>(API_URL + '/list/1/task/', task)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Task>('addTask'))
      )
  }
  deleteTask(task: Task): Observable<Task> {
    return this.http.delete<Task>(API_URL + '/task/' + task.id).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Task>('deleteTask'))
    )
  }
  updateTask(task): Observable<any> {
    const url = '${this.API_URL}/task/${task.id}';

    return this.http.put(url, task).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('update Product'))
    )
  }
  getAllTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get<Task[]>(API_URL + '/list/1/task/')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getTasks', []))
      );
  }
  getTaskById(id: number): Observable<Task> {
    const url = '${this.API_URL}/list/1/task/${id}';
    return this.http.get<Task>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Task>('getTask id=${id}'))
    )
  }
  toggleTaskComplete(task: Task) {
    task.complete = !task.complete;
    return this.updateTask(task);
  }
}
```

@Edit
Delete method on the server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/task/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteTask(@PathVariable String id) {
        taskService.deleteTask(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
```

Comment: Try `this.tasks.splice(this.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);` instead of `this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(t => t.id !== task.id);`. The only reason the value of `task.id` would be `0` is if it was never set on the server side when the `Task` is created.

Comment: I get error on server side java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity and id = 0; If I check it on postman it has value and if I refresh browser it is working.

Comment: The most probable reason is that the task returned by the backend has an ID equal to 0 instead of having its actual generated ID. Check that using your browser dev tools (network tab). If it's confirmed, then it's a problem of the server-side code, which has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: Thanks, you were right there was problem on the server-side code.